# Find minimal polynomial of matrix with some given property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ non-diagonizable complex matrix that satisfies the relation $A(A-2I_4)^2=0$. I want to find, with proof, all the possible forms that the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ of the matrix $A$ could have. For each of the above forms of $m_A(x)$, i want to write all the possible forms that the corresponding Jordan matrix of $A$ could have.

I have thought the following:

$A(A-2I_4)^2=0 \Rightarrow A(A^2-4A+4I_4)=0 \Rightarrow A^3-4A^2+4A=0$

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$.

We have that $Ax=\lambda x$.

Multiplying $A^3-4A^2+4A=0$ be $x$ we get that $(A^3-4A^2x+4A)x=0 \Rightarrow A^3x -4A^2x+4Ax=0 \Rightarrow \lambda^3 x-4 \lambda^2 x+4 \lambda x=0 \Rightarrow \lambda x(\lambda^2-4 \lambda+4)=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=0 \text{ or } (\lambda-2)^2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=0 \text{ or } \lambda=2$.

Thus the only minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(x)=x(x-2)$. Am I right?

Shouldn't one eigenvalue have a higher multiplicity? Or shouldn't we have one more eigenvalue? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Sure, the eigenvalues are $0$ and $2$. But $x(x-2)$ is NOT the minimal polynomial because you assume that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @amsmath Why do we have from the fact that $A$ is not diagonizable that $x(x-2)$ is not the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Because in that case, $\ker(A^2) = \ker A$ and $\ker((A-2I)^2) = \ker(A-2I)$. Hence, algebraic and geometric multiplicities concide.

Comment: @amsmath Did you see my question about the corresponding Jordan matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ satisfies the polynomial $p(X):=X(X-2)^2$, the minimal polynomial $m_A$ must divide $p$. Hence a priori you can have either

1. $m_A(X)=1$
2. $m_A(X)=X$
3. $m_A(X)=X-2$
4. $m_A(X)=(X-2)^2$
5. $m_A(X)=X(X-2)$
6. $m_A(X)=X(X-2)^2$

But a matrix is diagonalizable iff each factor appearing in its minimal polynomial (for each eigenvalue) is linear. Thus the only nondiagonalizable ones are cases 4 and 6.

To get the possible Jordan forms, We take into account that:

a. The multiplicity of the eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial determines the size of its largest Jordan block.

b. The sum of the sizes of its corresponding Jordan blocks determines its algebraic multiplicity.

c. The geometric multiplicity is found as the number of corresponding Jordan blocks.

For case (4): We have just one eigenvalue, $\lambda=2$, so it must have algebraic multiplicity $4$ (since we have matrices of size $4\times 4$). Its largest Jordan block has size $2$, so we can either have two blocks of size $2$ ($2+2=4$) or three blocks, one of size $2$ and two of size $1$ ($2+1+1=4$). In the first case the geometric multiplicity is $2$, in the second one it is $3$ (both lower than $4$, the algebraic multiplicity, so the matrices are indeed nondiagonalizable).

I'll let case (6) for you to complete!

Comment: I see... I have thought the following about the corresponding Jordan matrices. Am I right? @JoseBrox

$$$$

4) We have one 2x2 block for the eigenvalue 2.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$  

6) We have one 2x2 block for the eigenvalue 2 and one 1x1 block for the eigenvalue 0. 

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Evinda There are more possibilities. E.g. in (4) there can be two 2x2 Jordan blocks.

Comment: Is the one I wrote a right Jordan matrix? @amsmath

Comment: @Evinda Yes, it is. But, as I wrote, there are more possibilities.

Comment: @Evinda The multiplicity of the eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial only determines the size of its largest Jordan block, while the sum of the sizes of its corresponding Jordan blocks determines its algebraic multiplicity. On the other hand, the geometric multiplicity is found as the number of corresponding Jordan blocks.

Comment: @Evinda I have edited my answer to also address your Jordan form question